# How to parse JSON Data without third party library in swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I know there are several question available for same question, but none of them is working for me.
My code to convert from NSData to JSON is

```
var locateData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!

do {

responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locateData,   options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
let arrayStatuses: NSArray = responseObject["statuses"] as! NSArray
 print("Data items count: \(arrayStatuses.count)")

}

catch _ as NSError {

}
```

print count alway show 1, i need to create model class of dictionary available inside array

here is my sample JSON

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 27 07:31:26 +0000 2016",
      "name" :"shesh"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 27 07:31:26 +0000 2016",
      "name" :"shesh"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 27 07:31:26 +0000 2016",
      "name" :"shesh"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "Wed Jul 27 07:31:26 +0000 2016",
      "name" :"shesh"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use always native Swift collection types because the Foundation counterparts lack the important type information.

This code prints all values for the keys `text`, `truncated` and `created_at`

```
let locateData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!

do {
  if let responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locateData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject],
    arrayStatuses = responseObject["statuses"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    print("Data items count: \(arrayStatuses.count)")
    for status in arrayStatuses {
      let created = status["created_at"] as! String
      let truncated = status["truncated"] as! Bool
      let text = status["text"] as! String
      print("text: \(text), created: \(created), truncated: \(truncated)")
    }
  }

} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: 1 for it does work with sample data. still didn't got my solution

Comment: JSON parsing strongly depends on the structure of the source. Show the actual JSON.

Comment: please see actual JSON in given link https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8bu9ec9mnn99xd/JSON.txt?dl=0

Comment: i just need three field values i.e  text, created_at and truncated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118518/discussion-between-shesh-nath-and-vadian).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `Array enumerate()`

```
var locateData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!

do {

responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(locateData,   options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
let arrayStatuses: NSArray = responseObject["statuses"] as! NSArray
  for statue in arrayStatuses.enumerate(){
    print("Statue Name : \(statue.name)")
  }

}

catch _ as NSError {

}
```

Comment: `enumerate` is only useful if you need both `element` and `index` information

Comment: thanks, (statue.name) was syntax error so i changed to print("Statue Name : \(statue)") and output is  printing just first object of array